# Cannot get my head around Promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, q

I have written my code without even knowing what async was - this was at the beginning of the project when I was new to programming as a whole.

Now of course, I understand what they are. However, I cannot get my head around Promises. I have a /session async call which when I call it, passes me some profile variables but how to get it done, I have no idea. I have followed tutorials and get lost in it.

Can someone point how this should be written once and for all? I will be eternally grateful:

```
var getProfileID = function(){
    $http.get('/session')
        .then(function(res){
            return res.data.profileId;
        });
};

getProfileID()
.then(function(res) {
    $scope.profileID = res;
});
```

This looks very wrong to me but I am so clueless about Promises that I don't know where to begin.

PS: I am using Angular 1.6.4 and have injected $q

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `return $http.get....` it seems your problem is not with Promises, but understanding how to return a value from a function (in this case, the value is a Promise)

Comment: Can you elaborate a little please? It is true that I have avoided return so far everywhere in the code as I didn't need it.

Comment: you need your function to **return a Promise** in order to use that Promise - as it stands, your function returns `undefined` as having no return statement is equivalent to `return undefined` - I'm amazed you have avoided using return everywhere - your functions must be .... interesting

Comment: Please make sure you [debug your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): _Questions about a problem that can no longer be reproduced or that was caused by a simple typographical error_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should return `Promise` directly back from your function.

```
var getProfileID = function(){
  return $http.get('/session');
};
```

then use it with its response as below:

```
getProfileID().then(function(res) {
  $scope.profileID = res.data.profileId;
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that! Tried it out and worked like a charm.